# Playing audio file for specific time

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

Guys i able to play audio file using Mediaplayer. But i need to play a audio file for specific time.

Eg: play audio1.mp3 till 5 minutes.
The audio file is of 10 seconds only.But it should keep playing till 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 mediaplayerplayer.setLooping(true);<--- this lets the audio to loop...
```

and this is the countdown timer

```
MyCount counter;
Long s1;

counter= new MyCount(300000,1000);
counter.start();

public void asdf(View v){  <---- method for onclick of buttons pause and resuming timer
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:<-- for pause
            counter.cancel();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:<--- for resume
            counter= new MyCount(s1,1000);
            counter.start();
    }
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mediaplayer.stop();
        mediaplayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        s1=millisUntilFinished;
    }
}
```

this helps you to pause the mediaplayer also... along with timer.. and lets you play the song for complete 5 mins

Comment: counter= new MyCount(300000,1000);
    counter.start(); what is this please explain

Comment: this is for 60(seconds)*5(mins)*1000 .. as the value must be in milli seconds... counter starts from this value to 1 second...countdown timer.. from 5 mins..

Comment: but where am i going to start the mediaplayer.start();

Comment: you have your mediaplyer,start(); in your code... so put "counter= new MyCount(300000,1000);
    counter.start();".. after that line...

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main);mediaplyer,start();counter= new MyCount(300000,1000); counter.start(); is it fine

Comment: if you have button for playing and pausing audio player.. then instead of my "asdf" method... after pausing the player put counter.cancel(); and after resuming put these lines of code "counter= new MyCount(s1,1000);
         counter.start();"

Comment: but when i click on resume button only counter is resuming what about mediaplyer playing?

Comment: when you pause use "mediaplayer.pause();" and to resume player use mediaplayer.start();

Comment: thanks its working fine...can you please help me with other things also

Answer (score 0):

```
   //decleration 
MediaPlayer mp;
//specify the path of media file
String filepath="?";

//onCreate
  mp=new MediaPlayer();
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filepath);

               mp.setLooping(true);   
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityName.this, myUri);
           mp.start(); 
 new CountDownTimer(300000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.stop();
            }

            }
        }.start();
```