# Is there a way to increase ringtone time in android?

Tags: android, timing, ringtone

Am trying my first app in android. I have a query. Is there any possibility to set custom timings for a ringtone or set a full mp3 as tone without trimming the mp3? Please do help me? I don't find any attributes in Ringtone or Ringtone manager class.

Comment: see this links you may get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696000/playing-audio-file-for-specific-time                           http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: Thanx Allu. The link you gave seems to talk about media playback. Where as am trying to modify the default ringing time.For ex: If I have mp3 for 40 secs it plays 30sec as ringtone. Am looking to change the ringing time to 40sec. Thanks again for replying me.

Comment: if it is less time then we can use loop in audio manager to play sound for another time(like extra 10 sec) see this url u can get what is default ring and how to change the loop and all in this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Comment: Thanx Allu. Let me try this. Hope this helps me. Thanks again